# Clustering spatial lines in R by direction

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, clustering, spatial-cluster

There are tens of ways to cluster spatial points in R but I couldn't find any for spatial lines. What I would like to get is the average trajectory directions that each of these cyclones (spatial lines in my case) has over the territory of France similar to the possibility that `trajCluster` function from `openAir` library offers.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(maptools)
library(geosphere)
library(rgeos)

#load the world boundaries polygon
data(wrld_simpl)
contour <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME =='France',] #only the polygon for France

#download the data
x <- read.table("https://forms.naturwissenschaften.ch/imilast/_ERAinterim_1.5_1979_MTEX/ERAinterim_1.5_NH_M02_19790101_20121231_MTEX.txt?_ga=2.18919096.1825595846.1546710263-1112023567.1546710263", sep="", fill = T, nrows = 20000,
                header = F, skip = 2) # download only the first 20000 rows
colnames(x) <- c("Code","CycloneNo","StepNo","DateI10","Year","Month","Day","Time","LongE","LatN","Intensity1","Intensity2","Intensity3")

x <- x %>% filter(Code!=90) ##Just cleaning to remove those 'NA' rows
x <- x[x$LongE > -120 & x$LongE <= 120,] #subset only the traj between -120 and 120 longE
x$DateI10 <-as.POSIXct(paste(x$Year, x$Month, x$Day, x$Time, sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d-%H", tz = 'GMT')

# create an empty Spatial Line to be filled later
sline <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(Line(matrix(0, ncol = 2)), ID = NA)))
proj4string(sline) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
sline$time <- NA
sline$start <-NA
sline$distance <- NA
sline$mean <- NA

#calculate the lifetime for each track; keep only trajectories for France
for (k in unique(x$CycloneNo)){
  message(which(unique(x$CycloneNo) == k), " from ", length(unique(x$CycloneNo)))
  txt2 <- x[x$CycloneNo==k,]
  if (nrow(txt2) > 1){
    d <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(txt2$LongE, txt2$LatN)), ID= k)))
    proj4string(d) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
    d$time <- difftime(max(txt2$DateI10), min(txt2$DateI10), units = 'hours')
    d$start <-  as.character(min(txt2$DateI10)) # get the formation date
    d$distance <- lengthLine(d)/1000 # calculate distance
    d$mean <- mean(txt2$Intensity1) # average the sea level surface pressure
    if (gIntersects(d, contour, byid=TRUE) == TRUE){
      sline <- rbind(sline, d) #keep only trajectories crossing the France's territory
    }
  }
}

spplot(sline['time'],sp.layout = list(contour, lwd = 3), 
scales  = list(draw=T), main = 'Mean lifetime (h)') #plot the tracks

### what I would like to get is something like
library(openair)

traj <- importTraj(site = "paris", year = 2009)

## calculate clusters
traj <- trajCluster(traj, method = "Angle", type = "season",n.clusters = 4)
```

Is it possible to get something like this using my data? is clustering method appropriate here or I should some else (like PCA)?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to create a grouping column based on a timestamp, correct? This is a far cry from cluster analysis and would be query based and not a statistical model.

Comment: Well, it would be possible to calculate the mean value for each lat/long point and for each season (using the month column) - resulting one line. But I would need to see the frequency of each pattern so that's why I was thinking to a cluster analysis.

Comment: If you are trying to cluster them based on spatial proximity and similarity, you could start by clustering using the Hausdorff distance between all pairs of features. `gDistance` in package `rgeos` will compute this for you once you've converted that data frame to a spatial object.

Comment: I wonder if you've tried the new package, 'Rsharpie'? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's work through a Haussdorf clustering of lines.

We'll use the `sf` package for spatial data and distance calculations:

```
library(sf)
```

starting with your final `x`, lets group everything by cyclone number, make line features, and keep the number of points in the group:

```
cyclones = x %>% group_by(CycloneNo) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% summarize(n=mean(n),geometry=st_sfc(st_linestring(cbind(LongE, LatN))))
```

we keep the number of points because we can't make valid line features with one point and there are some single point cyclones. Let's drop them,

```
cyclones = cyclones[cyclones$n >1,]
```

Now make that data frame into a spatial data frame with a lat-long coordinate system:

```
cyclones = st_sf(cyclones)
st_crs(cyclones)=4326
```

Make a distance matrix using Haussdorf distance:

```
dmat = st_distance(cyclones, which="Haussdorf")
```

And feed that into a clustering function:

```
cl = hclust(as.dist(dmat))
```

Use `cutree` to find the five-cluster point and assign each track with a cluster ID. Plot...

```
cyclones$class5 = as.factor(cutree(cl, 5))
plot(cyclones[,"class5"])
```

[image]

Which looks interesting. Some cyclones seem to have at least part of themselves in another cluster, but that's the way the Haussdorf distance clustering works.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman. While this is a great tool for clustering lines, do you know what I could use in order to group the trajectories by their main directions? In the end I need to have several lines (like 3 - 4) and their relative frequency (as in the openair package - there is a function there called trajCluster which groups the HYSPLIT trajectories by their directions).

Comment: Its not clear to me yet what exactly you want to do. This answer is clustering lines by a distance measure analogous to clustering points or any other set of variables by a distance measure, and I can't think of any other general principle for clustering things. You need a distance measure and a clustering algorithm. It sounds like you want to cluster by *some function of* the lines, such as direction. Is the location important for your clusters? ie should all westerly cyclones make a cluster even if they are far apart geographically? If you could edit your Q for clarity that will help.

Comment: thank you Spacedman. I edited the code to be more relevant to my problem.